# Get the name of the class derived from cProfile statistics

Tags: python, profile, cprofile

I am trying to retrieve the class name of an code object in python. These code objects are the outputs of the statistics of a cProfile. An example of what I am trying to do below:

```
from cProfile import Profile
from typing import Any

class foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def __call__(self, *args: Any, **kwds: Any) -> Any:
        return args

p = Profile()
bar = foo()

with p:
    bar()

stats = p.getstats()
```

`stats` looks like the following:

```
         3 function calls in 0.000 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 cProfile.py:117(__exit__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 tmp.py:8(__call__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

I would like to know which class contained the callable in any profiler entry. Each of these `stats` are python `__code__` objects. Is there a simple/efficient way to get the class name of a function via the `__code__` object?

```
# Get foo's callable profile statistic

foo_callable = p.getstats()[2]
print(foo_callable)

_lsprof.profiler_entry(code=<code object __call__ at 0x7f9573925450, file "tmp.py", line 8>, callcount=1, reccallcount=0, totaltime=2.6400000000000003e-07, inlinetime=2.6400000000000003e-07, calls=None)
```